# How do I check if a string only contains one and zero?

Tags: c

I am trying to detect whether a string contains only the characters '0' and '1'. This is what I have so far:

```
    while (indexCheck < 32) {

        if ((input[indexCheck] != '0') && (input[indexCheck] != '1')) {

            printf("not binary ");
            indexCheck++;

        }  else if ((input[indexCheck] = '0') && (input[indexCheck] = '1')) {
            indexCheck++;
            printf("is binary ");

        } 

    }
```

I know why it returns "is binary" or "not binary" for every single character in the array, but I don't know how to fix this. I want it to return "is binary" once if the string is only made of '1' and '0', and the opposite if this is false. I'm new to C so all help is appreciated.

Comment: you should use `==` instead of `=` in the else if condition

Comment: Are you coming from Pascal/Delphi world? `if ((input[indexCheck] != '0') && (input[indexCheck] != '1')) ` is `if ( input[indexCheck] != '0' && input[indexCheck] != '1' )`, no need from parenthesis (in addition to `=` -> `==` error).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would make a function for this:

```
int isBinary(const char *input)
{
    for (int i = 0; input[i]; ++i)
        if (input[i] != '0' && input[i] != '1')
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Then you can call the function:

```
if (isBinary("0001110110101"))
    printf("is binary\n");
else
    printf("is not binary\n");
```

https://ideone.com/tKBCbf

Comment: Keeping it simple and readable is always the best idea indeed.

Answer (score 13):

Instead of looping manually through the string, you can see if it only contains certain characters by checking to see if [strspn()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strspn) returns the length of the string (By seeing if the index of the value it returns is the 0 terminator at the end of the string):

```
_Bool is_binary(const char *s) {
  if (!s || !*s) {
    return 0;
  }
  return s[strspn(s, "01")] == '\0';
}
```

Comment: A good and clever answer, but it doesn't help the OP in learning processing of characters manually.

Comment: Smart answer. Great post.

Answer (score 2):

You can stop looping through the string the moment you find a character which is neither '0' nor '1'. After the loop is terminated, you check whether or not you've reached the end of the string, i.e. the current character is a null character `'\0'`

```
while (*s == '0' || *s == '1') ++s;

if (*s)
    puts("not binary");
else
    puts("binary");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
while (indexCheck < 32) 
{
    if ((input[indexCheck] != '0') && (input[indexCheck] != '1'))
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        indexCheck++;
    } 
}
if (indexCheck == 32)
    printf("is binary ");
else
    printf("is not binary ");
```

Only when it has processed all elements and did not encounter a non 1-or-0 ends the loop with `indexCheck == 32` so you can use that to determine what to print.

Note also that your `else` condition is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int isBinary = 1;
    while (input[indexCheck] != '\0')
    {
        if (input[indexCheck] != '1' && input[indexCheck] != '0')
        {
            isBinary = 0;
            break;
        }
        ++indexCheck;
    }
    if (isBinary)
    {
        printf("binary");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("not binary");
    }
```

Check each element in string `input`. If `input[index]` is not `0` or `1` the flag `isBinary` becomes `0` and breaks `while`. And you do not need length of string.

Answer (score 1):

there is a block of code for you with comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STRING_SIZE 32 // Better to use #define for reusability

// Function prototype
int isBinary(char * testInput);

// Main program
int main(void)
{
    // Test inputs
    char testInputBinary[33] = "01010101010101010101010101010101";
    char testInputNotBinary[33] = "010101010101010101010101010101ab";

    // Test & collect results
    if (isBinary(testInputBinary))
    {
        printf("Binary ! \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not binary ! \n");
    }


    if (isBinary(testInputNotBinary))
    {
        printf("Binary ! \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not binary ! \n");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int isBinary(char * testInput)
{
    int loopIdx = 0; // Loop index
    int returnVal = 0; // 0: False, 1: True

    // iterate over string
    for (loopIdx = 0; loopIdx < STRING_SIZE; loopIdx++)
    {
        if(testInput[loopIdx] != '0' && testInput[loopIdx] != '1')
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    // If the loop is not broken, it means all characters are in binary form
    if (loopIdx == STRING_SIZE)
    {
        returnVal = 1;
    } // No need to writing else clause since returnVal = 0 at the beginning

    return returnVal;
}
```